# Redux createAsyncThunkFromAPI wrapper issue

Tags: typescript, redux, axios, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-rkekhf?file=app/redux/asyncThunkFromFetch.ts

We use the following helper to create thunks:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios, { AxiosPromise, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { store } from './store';

export const createAsyncThunkFromAPI = <ResponseSchema, RequestParams>(
  typePrefix: string,
  apiFunction: ApiFunction<RequestParams, ResponseSchema>
) => {
  return createAsyncThunk<ResponseSchema, RequestParams>(
    typePrefix,
    async (args, thunkApi) => {
      try {
        const response = await apiFunction(args);
        return response.data;
      } catch (e) {
        return thunkApi.rejectWithValue(e);
      }
    }
  );
};

type ApiFunction<RequestParams, ResponseSchema> = (
  axiosParams: RequestParams
) => AxiosPromise<ResponseSchema>;

export const getMobileOperatorsAPI = (): Promise<AxiosResponse<string[]>> => {
  return axios.get('https://api.com');
};

export default createAsyncThunkFromAPI;

const sliceName = 'mobile-operators';
export const fetchMobileOperators = createAsyncThunkFromAPI(
  `${sliceName}/fetchMobileOperators`,
  getMobileOperatorsAPI
);

store.dispatch(fetchMobileOperators()); //Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554)
store.dispatch(fetchMobileOperators({})); //Ouch!!!
```

One thing I hate about it, you cannot pass zero arguments to a thunk function created by the helper. However in our case it's still more convenient to use it instead of bare `createAsyncThunk` from `@redux/toolkit`

I tried to make a default parameter for payload creator with no success. But I don't really understand what I'm doing here.

How to tweak `createAsyncThunkFromAPI` to infer `args` from API function?

How to implement the same idea in a proper way?

What knowledge do I miss to be able to resolve this problem by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `<ResponseSchema, RequestParams = never>`

You are very close and just missing one tiny little thing.  Your thunk factory will infer the type for the generics `ResponseSchema` and `RequestParams` by looking at the types of the `apiFunction`.  This particular `apiFunction` has no argument so the `RequestParams` is getting inferred as `unknown`.  We want to make sure that it gets inferred as `never` instead.  Therefore we add a default value `RequestParams = never`.  This means that no `args` will be accepted when the `RequestParams` cannot be inferred.

```
export const createAsyncThunkFromAPI = <ResponseSchema, RequestParams = never>(
```

After making this change, the desired usage has no error and your workaround solution *does* have an error.

```
store.dispatch(fetchMobileOperators()); // okay!
store.dispatch(fetchMobileOperators({})); // Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.(2554)
```

---

There's one last thing to check which is to make sure that it still works properly when there *is* a required argument.  I [added an additional example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-hxj2be?file=app%2Fredux%2FasyncThunkFromFetch.ts) and sure enough it works perfectly.  We get an error when the argument is missing and no error when an argument is provided.

Comment: I couldn't even imagine I can get such an amazing answer. Many thanks @Linda